# Unable to load service using `service xxx start`

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a service with a script in the `/etc/init.d/aaa` with `sudo service aaa start`, there's such an script with content like these:

```
!/bin/sh



CATA_HOME=/home/pi/proxy

case $1 in
    start)
            sh $CATA_HOME/startup.sh
            ;;
    stop)
            sh $CATA_HOME/shutdown.sh
            ;;
    restart)
            sh $CATA_HOME/shutdown.sh
            sh $CATA_HOME/startup.sh
            ;;
    *)

            echo 'please use : aaa {start | stop | restart}'
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

and the result tends to be `Failed to start aaa.service: Unit aaa.service not found.`

Comment: "Unit aaa.service not found" means your operating system uses systemd. Instead of a SysV-style init script (the script you have here), you need to build a systemd unit file. That's for the better -- SysV init systems are awful.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48717116/getting-service-unavailable-when-starting-tomcat-using-systemd -- that question incorporates a systemd service definition for Tomcat you should be able to crib off of.

Comment: (Very, very short explanation: The instructions that told you to create an init script were written for an ancient distro, and you're using a modern one. Though even with an ancient distro, there are better ways to do process supervision -- I'm personally a fan of [Runit](http://smarden.org/runit/); a runit script for Tomcat [is 5 lines](http://smarden.org/runit/runscripts.html#tomcat), would be 3 without the whitespace, and provides a bunch of features -- like automatic restart on failure -- that the init.d approach cannot).