# "service xxx start" (ONLY the "start") not working on Redhat

Tags: bash, systemd, sysv

We have been using an open-source OCSP responder (OpenCA OCSP Responder), and I am trying to get it working on RHEL 7.  The project is quite old, and I don't think is being maintained actively anymore.  Anyway, I was able to get it to work on RHEL 7 finally, but it uses an older-style startup code (/etc/init.d/ocspd) and I was noticing that when I do:

```
service ocspd start
```

the OCSPD process is not starting.

The startup script has several other options for starting, that DO work, e.g.,

```
service ocspd start-debug
```

works fine.

It is only:

```
service ocspd start
```

that doesn't work and it's been kind of driving me batty!!

It is acting like, with the "service ocspd start", it is not even executing the code in the /etc/init.d/ocspd file?

So I've been searching around here and I found this:

[Unable to load service using `service xxx start`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564476/unable-to-load-service-using-service-xxx-start)

and I think that thread (SystemV vs. systemd) may explain why ONLY the "start" doesn't work, but if the /etc/init.d/ocspd script is not the correct way for RHEL 7, then I am not 100% clear what I should replace that /etc/init.d/ocspd script with?

FYI, here is a snippet of the current /etc/init.d/ocspd:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Startup script for the OCSPD responder
#
# chkconfig: 345 85 15
# description: OpenCA OCSP Responder
# processname: openca-ocspd

prefix="/apps/oracle/ocspd";
sbin="${prefix}/sbin";
etc="${prefix}/etc/ocspd";
run="${prefix}/var/run";

# Source function library.
[ -f "/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions" ] && . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

ocspd="${sbin}/ocspd";
conf="${etc}/ocspd.xml";

# [Begin] Create pid file under /var/tmp
pidfile="/var/tmp/ocspd.pid";
# [End] Create pid file under /var/tmp
pid=`cat $pidfile 2>/dev/null`;

if [ -z "$pid" ] ; then
        shellPid=$$
        ocspPid=`pgrep ocspd`
        pid=`echo $ocspPid | sed -e "s|$shellPid||" | sed -e "s| ||g"`
fi

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
        start)
                echo -n "Starting OCSP Responder: "
                kill -s 0 "$pid" 2>/dev/null &&
                echo "ERROR, responder is already running" ||
                ( ${ocspd} -c "${conf}" -d && echo "Done." ||
                        echo "Error, check logs!" );
                ;;
  start-verbose)
                echo -n "Starting OCSP Responder: "
                kill -s 0 "$pid" 2>/dev/null &&
                        echo "ERROR, responder is already running" ||
                        ( ${ocspd} -c "${conf}" -d -v && echo "Done." ||
                                echo "Error, check logs!" );
                ;;
  start-debug)
                echo -n "Starting OCSP Responder: "
                kill -s 0 "$pid" 2>/dev/null &&
                        echo "ERROR, responder is already running" ||
                        ( ${ocspd} -c "${conf}" -d -v -debug && echo "Done." ||
                            echo "Error, check logs!" );
                echo "Done."
                ;;

.
.
.
esac

exit 0
```

I guess ideally, I'd like to find out how/what to replace the current /etc/init.d/ocspd with?  I don't think we need ALL of the options.  FYI< here's the options that it supports currently:

```
  OpenCA OCSPD - Startup Script
  (c) 2002-2022 by Massimiliano Pala and OpenCA Labs
  All Rights Reserved

    Usage: /etc/init.d/ocspd [ target ]

  Where [ target ] is one of:
  * start ............: Start OCSPD (normal)
  * start-debug ......: Start OCSPD (debug)
  * start-wrongsig ...: Start OCSPD (wrong signatures)
  * stop .............: Stops the OCSPD
  * status ...........: Returns the status of OCSPD
  * reload-crl .......: Forces reloading of CRLs
  * restart ..........: Restarts OCSPD (normal)
```

Thanks,
Jim

EDIT 1:  I forgot to mention that when I do "service ocspd start" vs. "service ocspd start-debug", the output is different, which has been leading me to believe that, for some reason, when "service ocspd start" is run, the /etc/init.d/ocspd script is actually not being run, but something ELSE is being attempted.

When I do "service ocspd start" the output is:

```
[root@ip-192-168-133-209 ec2-user]# service ocspd start
Starting ocspd (via systemctl):                            [  OK  ]
```

But when I do "service ocspd start-debug" the output is:

```
[root@ip-192-168-133-209 ec2-user]# service ocspd start-debug
Starting OCSP Responder: Done.
Done.
```

The 2 lines that are output in the latter case, "Starting OCSP Responder: Done." and "Done." are coming from the code I posted for the "ocspd" script, but the:

```
Starting ocspd (via systemctl):                            [  OK  ]
```

line when I run the former, is coming directly from systemctl(?) and doesn't seem like the /etc/init.d/ocspd script is executed at all.

Also, I did another experiment where I changed the following line in the /etc/init.d/ocspd:

```
        start)
```

to:

```
        startX)
```

and if I then run:

```
service ocspd startX
```

the ocspd gets started ok, and it outputs:

```
[root@ip-192-168-133-209 ec2-user]# service ocspd startX
Starting OCSP Responder: Done.
```

EDIT 2:  I added the "set -x" and "set +x" suggested by Dudi Boy and, with the ocspd NOT running I ran "service ocspd start" and got the following output in the /var/log/messages:

```
May 15 11:53:55 ip-192-168-133-209 systemd: Starting SYSV: OpenCA OCSP Responder...
May 15 11:53:55 ip-192-168-133-209 ocspd: + echo -n 'Starting OCSP Responder: '
May 15 11:53:55 ip-192-168-133-209 ocspd: Starting OCSP Responder: + kill -s 0 9169
May 15 11:53:55 ip-192-168-133-209 ocspd: + echo 'ERROR, responder is already running'
May 15 11:53:55 ip-192-168-133-209 ocspd: ERROR, responder is already running
May 15 11:53:55 ip-192-168-133-209 ocspd: + set +x
May 15 11:53:55 ip-192-168-133-209 systemd: Started SYSV: OpenCA OCSP Responder.
```

BUT, even though it says it started, when I do "ps -ef | grep ocspd" the ocspd is NOT running!

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to start diagnosis with debug trace:

Insert `set -x` and `set +x` into strategic places in `/etc/init.d/ocspd`

As in the following:

```
# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
        start)
                set -x
                echo -n "Starting OCSP Responder: "
                kill -s 0 "$pid" 2>/dev/null &&
                echo "ERROR, responder is already running" ||
                ( ${ocspd} -c "${conf}" -d && echo "Done." ||
                        echo "Error, check logs!" );
                set +x
                ;;
```

Inspect the respective service log. For detailed commands execution with actual variable expansion.

Comment: Hi - I will try that but in my original post, I had mentioned that when I did the "service ocspd start" it seems like it is not even running the /etc/init.d/ocspd script, but I had forgotten to mention that I had added some debug "echo" lines in the "start" branch of the case, and those echoes don't execute when I do "service ocspd start".  I will add that info to my original post and trhen try adding the "set" commands after this.

Comment: I added the set -x and set +x and will add the output to the original post.